# Intellij-IDEA: Expand import blocks if they have errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a way to get intellij to expand import blocks if they have an error in them?  By default it folds them.  I'd like this to stay the default unless there's an error in them.

Comment: Mine doesn't let me fold them in if they have an error already. If you mean syntax error, it shouldn't fold in the first place. If it's an optimization error (unused import) I'm not sure, will look up

Comment: @SterlingArcher This is a situation where I deleted a class that is imported by others.

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically, but you can get to it quickly by pressing ctrl-home and then F2.